# extract duplicates into a new df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df that looks this:

```
ID  Name  Long   Lat
1   X     2      3
5   Z     2      3
8   U     1      5
```

Some rows are duplicates for the Long or Lat values. I know this since this returns me a value greater than 0.

```
len(df['Long'])-len(df['Long'].drop_duplicates())
```

How can I delete the duplicate rows (where long/lat) is being repeated, such that I extract the repeating duplicate rows into a new df (along with the header)?

For instance, my original df should now be

```
ID  Name  Long   Lat
1   X     2      3
8   U     1      5
```

and the df2 should be

```
ID  Name  Long   Lat
5   Z     2      3
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas-dataframe-duplicated):

```py
mask = df.duplicated(["Long", "Lat"])

print(df[mask])
print(df[~mask])
```

Prints:

```
   ID Name  Long  Lat
1   5    Z     2    3

   ID Name  Long  Lat
0   1    X     2    3
2   8    U     1    5
```